# Omitting unlisten() when using history.listen() - bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, listener, browser-history

I have a child Element that's listening to the app's browser history. I can't think of a scenario where I would want to unlisten(). I want to check the previous page the user is on as long as the user is using the app.